# How to change icon on click using <i> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll include my code below as well as a link to my codepen. I'm messing around trying to learn html/css and I'm trying to incorporate dark mode into the website. I'm struggling to get the icon to change from a sun to a moon and vice versa when the icon is clicked, sun indicating you'll change to light mode and moon indicating you'll change to dark moon when clicked.

I'm also having issues with the first paragraph of text sitting low on the screen on loadup, rather than it being centered on your screen- if anyone has an idea as to how to fix this it would be much appreciated! (it goes much lower when in fullscreen than when taking up half of the screen horizontally)

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

codepen: https://codepen.io/StuartGroom/pen/Rwgypyr

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

    var themeIcon = document.getElementById('themeIcon');
    if(document.classList.contains("fas fa-sun")){
        themeIcon.addClass("fas fa-moon").removeClass("fas fa-sun");
        
    }
    else{
        themeIcon.addClass("fas fa-sun").removeClass("fas fa-moon");
    }

}
```

```
    :root{
        --primary-color: white;
        --secondary-color: black;
    }

    .dark-mode{
        --primary-color: black;
        --secondary-color: white;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
    }

    .hero {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;

    }


    .hero .text-box {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 50% auto; /*makes the textbox half way down and auto the center*/
        color: var(--secondary-color);
    }

    .text-box h1 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    .text-box p1 {
        line-height: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .text-box p2 {
        line-height: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .text-box .btn {
        margin: 30px 0; /*how far away button is from text above (p2)*/
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 18px; /*how far the lines of button are from text*/
        
        width: 85px;

        color: var(--primary-color);
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        text-decoration: none;
        background: var(--secondary-color);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .text-box .btn:hover {        /*this does nothing???*/
        background: #f44336;
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }

    .sidebar {
        height: 335px;
        width: 60px;
        background: var(--primary-color);
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 25%;
        right: 50px;
        transform: translateY(-75%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .icon-box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin: 5px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .side-text {
        min-width: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #f44336;
        margin-right: 5px;
        line-height: 0;
        color: var(--primary-color);

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s; /*this transitions the side-text coming out*/
       
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .icon {
        min-width: 50px;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        
    }

    /*make the icons red and spaced out nice*/
    .icon .fas {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #f44336;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .icon .fab {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #f44336;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .icon .far {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #f44336;
        line-height: 50px;
    }


    /*when hover make icon background red*/
    .icon-box:hover .icon {
        background-color: #f44336;
    }

    /*when hover make icons white*/
    .icon-box:hover .icon .fas {
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }

    .icon-box:hover .icon .fab {
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }

    .icon-box:hover .icon .far {
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }

    /*when hover make the sidetext come out*/
    .icon-box:hover .side-text {
        min-width: 140px; /*min-width was 0px above, when hover we change it to make it visible*/
    }




    /*here starts social sidebar stuff*/
    /*here starts social sidebar stuff*/
    /*here starts social sidebar stuff*/
    /*here starts social sidebar stuff*/
    /*here starts social sidebar stuff*/

    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
       
    }

    /*here we chanaged to make pos fixed and bottom = 0, height = 200 to make it fit the bottom*/
    .wrapper .socialSidebar {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 220px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .wrapper .socialSidebar .vertical {
        border-left: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-left: 60px; /*centers vertical line with icons*/
        
    }



    /*makes the icon glow when hovered over*/
    .wrapper .socialSidebar ul li:hover a {
        color: #f44336;
        /*background: blue;*/
        top: 50px;
        transform: scale(1.5); /*enlarges icon by 150% when hovered over
    */
    }


    /*sets color of the icon*/
    .wrapper .socialSidebar a {
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: var(--secondary-color);
    }

    .anchor {       /*used to center the screen on different sections when href links are clicked (sidebar icons)*/
        display: block;
        transform: translateY(-50vh);
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

        <title>StuartGroomSD</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/935b67cf83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        
        <script type = "JS.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="hero">

            <div class="text-box">
                <p1>
                    Hi, my name is
                </p1>
                <h1> Stuart Groom. </h1>
                <span class="anchor" id="home"></span>
                <h2> I'm a third year Computer Science student</h2>
                <p2>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p2>

                <a class="btn" href="mailto: stuartgroom98@gmail.com" target="_blank">Contact me</a>

            </div>




            <div class="sidebar">

                <a href="#home">
                    <div class="icon-box">

                        <div class="side-text">
                            Home    <!-- text for side text-->

                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">

                            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>


                            <!-- here we made the entire icon box + side text have a href (so the entire box is clickable). clickable event to take to ID about(ID is shown by #)
                            below in second_box we have the h1 tag
                            have id set to ="about" and this is what
                            we jump to
                        -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>



                <a href="#about">
                    <div class="icon-box">
                        <div class="side-text">
                            About me

                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-male"></i>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>


                <a href="#projects">
                    <div class="icon-box">
                        <div class="side-text">
                            Projects

                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>


                <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JCYgFEqjdou8mijKhevPHuMBm1s9dl25lOZ-3HNJh6E/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">
                    <div class="icon-box">
                        <div class="side-text">
                            Resume

                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="far fa-file"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                
                <a href="#" onClick="myFunction()">
                    <div class="icon-box">
                        <div class="side-text" >
                            Dark Mode
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-moon" id="themeIcon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>


            </div>




            <div class="about_me">
                <div class="text-box">
                    <h1> About me </h1>
                    <span class="anchor" id="about"></span>
                    <p2>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p2>


                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="projects">
                <div class="text-box">
                    <h1> Projects </h1>
                    <span class="anchor" id="projects"></span>
                    <p2>
                        testing github works
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p2>
                </div>
            </div>






            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="socialSidebar">
                    

                    <ul>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;"> <a href="mailto: stuartgroom98@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>

                        <li style="list-style-type: none;"> <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                        <!-- replace hashtag with github link-->

                        <li style="list-style-type: none;">   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/stuart-groom-5baa4b196/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="vertical"></div>


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `var themeIcon = document.themeIcon` from? Try `var themeIcon = document.getElementById('themeIcon');`

Comment: Your themeIcon variable is invalid. You need to target it by using a valid selector logic. Also, you're using plain JS, so hasClass() is not a valid method/function. You need to do classList.includes(), which is the plain JS way.

Comment: I edited it and got this error in codepen, "Uncaught TypeError: themeIcon.hasClass is not a function". I changed to if(document.classList.contains("fas fa-sun")){ and it still doesn't work

Comment: classList is looking for an element, not `document.body` for starters. In your `if` statement you're trying to have a condition for something that will never be found. Switch that to instead identify if the element is actually there as the condition instead of `document.classList` since the document wouldn't have that selector but the element would.

Answer (score 0):

in your if condition you have `document.classList` instead of `themeIcon.classList`, causing it to not find the correct value. Also addClass/removeClass are not real functions (maybe they are from some library) so i replaced them with standard `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`

```
  var themeIcon = document.getElementById('themeIcon');
  if(themeIcon.classList.contains("fa-sun")){
    themeIcon.classList.add("fa-moon")
    themeIcon.classList.remove("fa-sun");
  }
  else{
    themeIcon.classList.add("fa-sun")
    themeIcon.classList.remove("fa-moon");
  }
```

https://codepen.io/jacekWyroba/pen/zYzjagB

Comment: Thank you so much Jacek! It works great